Kotlinの非同期処理
私の解釈ではkotlinでAndroidアプリ開発をする際にユーザー操作を止めてはならないという認識なのですが、ネットワークからデータベースに接続し書込み処理をする際にはどのようにすればいいのでしょうか？
単にviewModelScopeを使うと登録ボタン等を押した後にユーザーがfragmentを遷移し、viewModelが破棄され、登録がキャンセルされる可能性があると思います。
そもそもこういうよくあるパターンの解決策はどこかに提示されているものでは無いのでしょうか？
